# html 5 upload video from mobile set resolution

Tags: html, video, mobile, upload, resolution

I want to upload a video file from an html 5 page opened in a mobile device, to a server running flask.
I have this for the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-muted">How To Upload a File</h3>
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <div>

      <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will allow to select the camera/camcoder when opening via chrome on iOS/Android.
he iOS resolution is about 400*320 and the Android about 3000*2000, and so the  generated video file for a 5 sec recording is about 300k on iOS (which is OK), and 16MB on Android. so The Android file is too big for upload...

Is it possible to set the resolution for the recording?

Comment: I switched to use WebRTC, which lets me select the resolution on Android devices. However this does not work on iOS devices, as WebRTC is not supported yet